# Preselecting a value for dropdownlist

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

I have my javascript code as below:

```
var myobservablearray = ko.observableArray(["toys", "books"]);
var myselectedobservable = ko.observable();

var myotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray([{
  "toys": [{
    "name": "Bungle",
    "isselected": true
  }, {
    "name": "George"
  }, {
    "name": "Zippy"
  }]
}, {
  "books": [{
    "name": "Book1",
    "isselected": true
  }, {
    "name": "Book2"
  }, {
    "name": "Book3"
  }]
}]);
var myselectedotherobservable = ko.observable();
```

I wish to create a cascading drop downlist

My first dropdowncode is as below..

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.myobservablearray,  value: myselectedobservable"></select>
```

How do I create a cascading dropdown such that the preselected value of the selected option in that drop down is the value which has isselected=true.

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several things going on here. You've got a structure that maps out the values for each of toys and books. You will use that to get the options for the dependent select, but it doesn't need to be an array itself.

The main select is straightforward, with options and a value. The dependent select will get its options from a computed observable which will also set the value to the entry that has `isselected` set.

If you also want the selected value to update which item has `isselected` set, there's probably some more code rearranging to be done.

**Update** After the dependent list is updated, Knockout needs a little time to set up the select. By default, it will set the first item in the list to be selected. To make sure our default is selected after the list is setup, I added a `setTimeout` (and separated the default selection from the list computed).

```js
vm = (function() {
  var myobservablearray = ko.observableArray(["toys", "books"]),
    value1 = ko.observable(),
    value2 = ko.observable();

  var dependentOptions = {
    "toys": [{
      "name": "Bungle"
    }, {
      "name": "George",
      "isselected": true
    }, {
      "name": "Zippy"
    }],
    "books": [{
      "name": "Book1",
      "isselected": true
    }, {
      "name": "Book2"
    }, {
      "name": "Book3"
    }]
  };

  var options2 = ko.computed(function() {
    if (value1() === undefined) return;
    return dependentOptions[value1()];
  });

  options2.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < newValue.length; ++i) {
        var item = newValue[i];
        if (item.isselected) {
          console.debug("Found selected");
          value2(item);
        }
      }
    }, 0);
  });

  return {
    options1: myobservablearray,
    options2: options2,
    value1: value1,
    value2: value2
  };
}());

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: options1, value: value1"></select>
<select data-bind="options: options2, optionsText: 'name', value: value2"></select>
```

Comment: its not working correctly.. when the app starts, it shows toys and George but if you change 'toys' to Books and 'toys' again, it shows 'Bungle' which is the first value and not the isselected value

Comment: I saw the code, it must work the first time the code runs and then stop.., u can see if u run the code

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the comment at first. I deleted my earlier comment about a minute later. I've updated the code.

Comment: Why is SetTimeout used with delay of 0

Comment: Because all JavaScript needs to do is finish the things it already has scheduled before coming back to this task.